# Sending Created Plot via Mail

Tags: python, pandas, email, matplotlib

I Used MySQLdb to built up the connection to my SQL database.
Then I limited the database with

```
Cursor = connection.cursor()
anz = Cursor.execute(myquery)
```

Then I Made a Dataframe out of it

```
df = DataFrame(anz, columns = ['likeval','count'])
```

Then I plotted it

```
df.plot(kind='hist', x='Anzahl', y='count')
```

I imported MySQLdb, pandas and matplotlib.pyplot

So now I want to know how I send this plot via e-mail to someone.
I want to do it with the same Code and don't want to save the graph.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to save the figure to a virtual file object:

```py
import io

img_format = 'png'

df.plot(...)

f = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format=img_format)
f.seek(0)
```

Now, `f` contains the image data and can be `read` from like a file:

```py
img_data = f.read()
```

Next, let's create the email message:

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
# Add From/To/Subject fields by using msg like a dictionary
```

There are two options for sending the image by email:

1. Base64-encode it and pass it inside inside an HTML `<img>` tag
2. Add it as an attachment

Option 1:

```py
from base64 import b64encode

msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
msg.set_content(f'''<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="data:image/{img_format};base64, {b64encode(img_data).decode('ascii')}">
</body>
</html>''')
```

Option 2:

```py
msg.add_attachment(img_data, maintype='image', subtype=img_format)
```

Finally, send the email:

```py
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.starttls()
s.login(...)
s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Note: I haven't tested these but they shouldn't be too far from working.

Comment: Let me know how it goes if you try one of the options, I’d like to see if it works

Comment: Option 1 works for me, thanks. Didn't try option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Tried option 2, works for me. Sent a matplotlib table. The header row from the table is missing though in the sent email message. Figuring that out now along with adding a subject.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31399537)